# Axon Saga subscribing mode concurrency issue

Tags: axon, saga

I'm seeing an unexpected behaviour when switching from tracking to subscribing mode in my Saga using Axon 4.3.5

It seems, in subscribing mode, there are two sagas created for the same association key-value when two threads reach two @StarSaga methods simultaneously.
Am I missing something?

I've got this to reproduce it:

```
@Saga
@ProcessingGroup("Saga")
public class RaceSaga {

    @Inject
    protected transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "executionId")
    public void on(Exec exec) {
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(new CreateExecCommand(exec.getExecutionId(), exec.getDescription()));
    }

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "executionId")
    public void on(Risk risk) {
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(new CreateRiskCommand(risk.getExecutionId(), risk.getResult()));
    }
}

@IntegrationTest
class RaceConditionTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private EventGateway eventGateway;
    @Autowired
    private SagaStore sagaStore;

    @Test
    void sagaRace() {
        var execId = UUID.randomUUID();

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> eventGateway.publish(new Exec(execId.toString(), "desc")));
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> eventGateway.publish(new Risk(execId.toString(), "OK")));

        var association = new AssociationValue("executionId", execId.toString());
        await().during(5, SECONDS)
                .untilAsserted(() -> assertThat(sagaStore.findSagas(RaceSaga.class, association))
                        .hasSize(1));
    }
}
```

The test passes when using tracking mode but fails with subscribing. (yml config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, this is expected behavior given the test set up, but it requires some explanation.

Know that the following is the main difference between Subscribing (SEP) and Tracking Event Processors (TEP):

- `SubscribingEventProcessor` - Invoked in the thread which published the event on the `EventBus`, resembling a push mechanism.
- `TrackingEventProcessor` - Invoked in a separate thread retrieving events from the `EventStore`, resembling a pull mechanism.

This ensures the regardless of the approach for concurrent publication of events, the TEP will ensure the event handling order in the case.

When it comes to the SEP, things are slightly different, for which we need to dive into the implementation slightly. You can assume that the publication of two or more events isn't overly strange. Plenty an Aggregate implementation would do this, given the right requirement within the domain. The framework has a way of grouping these transactions of multiple events in one batch. For this, it uses the `UnitOfWork`. If you would for example enter a command handling function of an Aggregate, you are ensured a `UnitOfWork` is active to coordinate the life cycle. On of these tasks is to pair up the events in one batch for publication.

In your test case, you are however using the `EventGateway` directly. Inherently perfectly fine, but the test is set up without starting a `UnitOfWork` to coordinate these two events as to happen in order. Diving through the code to see how publication to a SEP would work, you would land up in the `AbstractEventProcessor` at this stage. A validation is done to check whether a `UnitOfWork` is active when `EventProcessor#publish(List<EventMessage>)` is invoked. If so, the events are added to the right phase of the `UnitOfWork`.

When no `UnitOfWork` (UoW) is active though, the handlers will be invoked immediately.

So, when using a `TrackingEventProcessor`, it is the framework which will have consciously started a UoW to batch the events in to handle in order. When using a `SubscribingEventProcessor`, this work is left to the user, making the assumption that users typically will move through the regular flow of [command handling -> event publication -> event handling], which will ensure a UoW is active. Since that is not the case in your integration test, both publish operation will immediately invoke the `RaceSaga`'s `SagaManager`, creating two instances due to concurrency.

Note that it is recommended to use the TEP for processes like these. Using a SEP for Saga's could mean you will loose some events during a (faulty) shutdown of your application. As SEP is a push mechanism, there is no means to recover from these "lost" (from the perspective of your event processor) events. A TEP will resolve this issue, as it is handling events on it's own accord and keeping track of the process.

Trusting this clarifies things for you @matpiera.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's what we had found after some research. We were still surprised by the fact that Sagas are supported with no TEP.

The test is actually a real scenario as we have two external messages coming through Kafka. Regarding the message lost comment, would it be enough to hold the Kafka acknowledge until the message has been fully processed?

Comment: From the perspective of the Saga there is _zero_ concern about the `EventProcessor` being used; it just receives the events, potentially from several sources if necessary. Know that the Kafka Extension can also be set up as a TEP as you might know, hence omitting the problem on your end. However, you could thus also benefit from Kafka's ability to replay events.With your last question by the way, are you talking about the Consumer Acknowledgment? Thus, the ack stemming from the `KafkaSubscribableMessageSource`?

Comment: I see. That makes sense. We're using a different library for Kafka but yes, I'm talking about the consumer ack and also making use of replying features.

Comment: I'd very much like to help you with Kafka specifics, but sadly that's by no means my strong suit. When it comes to Axon's Kafka Extension, I can definitely help you out (as I am by all means the main committer on that right now), but if you are using a different library, I'd find it hard to give you the right guidance on the matter.